# What IP address is a new email account associated with?

Tags: email, ip, geolocation

If records are subpoenaed from google will they reveal internal IP or external IP addresses of a email account? For example if an email address is made and an email is sent using and iPad and home wifi will it reveal the same IP address or different address used to create and send an email from a different home wifi?

Comment: Is a subpoena relevant to the question? Or are you asking about the technical capability of Gmail's logging capability?

Answer (score 1):

For the legal side of the question, you'll need to consult a lawyer in your own jurisdiction; legal requests for information are handled differently in Great Britain, Russia, Mexico, the United States, Japan, and so on.

For the IP address side, as a purely practical matter, an IP address of 192.168.1.2 really isn't going to be helpful to anyone, ever.

Your internal IP address isn't really visible outside your* network barring cloud backups,  ISP end-user records if you let your ISP equipment generate your internal IP addresses, or if you use Internet-addressable static IP's internally, or if you're on IPv6..., or if your Flash or Java or Javascript or whatever leaked it to a site you visited, or...  Ok, it's not uncommon for it to be visible.  For consumer devices, it is uncommon for it to be unique enough to be meaningful.

Thus, IF someone's looking for an IP address, without the external address it's unlikely (but possible, if you're using 10.88.66.22 internally, perhaps) that the internal address is useful.  On NAT systems, with the external address, then the internal address plus a date and time suddenly has value.

*If you've outsourced your network, then the outsourcers can see it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question?

- connections to google (to read your emails or to construct a new message) will be logged with your public ip-address at the side of google
- The email that is sent will be sent throught google's mail servers and will therefor only hold ip-address information of google's mailserver.
- your internal ip-address will be logged on your internal device (router/firewall/dhcp-server/...) if this is a device that logs anything at all (who manages this devices?)
- Normally, your ISP will have records of what public ip-address you had (because most of the time this changes dynamicaly every couple days). And some ISP's will also log the kind of traffic. However connections to gmail will be ssl so they will not be able to see what you sent to google, only that you had an ssl connection with google.

I hope this already clarifies some of the technical side of your question. However as I don't understand your question completely, I don't know if I have answered it.